# Why is the slope of regression line always smaller than the slope of SD line?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I'm learning linear regression and according to my learning materials the slope of regression line equals $r\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$ where $-1\leqslant r \leqslant 1$ is the correlation coefficient and $\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$ is the slope of the SD line. Since r is always less or equal than 1, the increase of x by 1 $\sigma_x$ can cause at most 1$\sigma_y$ increase in y but why is it so? Why the relationship between two variables cannot be arranged in such a way that increasing x by 1$\sigma_x$ would cause 2$\sigma_y$ increase in y?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The variance of $y$ can be decomposed in an explained part $\sigma^2_{Y,e}=\dfrac{\text{cov}_{XY}}{\sigma^2_X}=\rho_{XY}\dfrac{\sigma^2_Y}{\sigma_X^2}$ and a residual, unexplained part, $\sigma^2_{Y,u}=(1-\rho_{XY})\dfrac{\sigma^2_Y}{\sigma_X^2}$.

The regression line appropriately uses the explained part, which reflects the linear model and minimizes the residual error.

The SD line (which does not appear to be a common concept) integrates the unexplained variance and for this reason has little use. Other lines with "forced" slopes would be of even less use.